# Extremely low Time to First Byte on Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

How can I improve the Time to First Byte on Google Cloud Storage? I am storing images on Google Cloud Storage and it takes 1-2 seconds forTime to First Byte.

Comment: Can you spin up a GCE instance and try to make an upload from there to discard your network as a root cause? Also how do you perform an upload (e.g. Dev Console, JSON API via a client lin, etc.)?

Comment: Might be helpful to include "gsutil perfdiag" output, which gives some useful info.

Comment: This is for first byte to download or upload?